# RSelenium will not scroll to bottom of page

Tags: r, web-scraping, scroll, rselenium

I need to load the entire page to scrape all the data from the table. I'm having issues with the java portion in the for loop. I've tried adjusting various sleep times (1-5 seconds), but that hasn't helped either. What can I do to fix it?

```
library(RSelenium)
library(netstat)
library(tidyverse)

# start server
remote_driver <- rsDriver(browser = 'firefox',
                          verbose= FALSE,
                          port = free_port())

rd <- remote_driver$client
rd$open()
rd$navigate('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EDJI/history?period1=915408000&period2=1396396800&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d&includeAdjustedClose=true')
rd$maxWindowSize()


for (i in 1:40){
  rd$executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
  Sys.sleep(3) 
}
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you. Just curious. How did you know the y scroll position needed to be increased?

Comment: Interesting! I thought the loop would have fixed that. Great info, thanks again.

Comment: @MrFlick you should add your this as an approved answer

Comment: @bandcar you should mark this an accepted answer, once added and upvote it if this is your resolution. This will help the community if they are searching for a similar issue or the same

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep increasing the y scroll position. For example

```
rd$executeScript(paste0("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight * ", i , ");"))
```

You can check in the browser that `document.body.scrollHeight` never changes. And `window.scrollTo` uses an absolute `x` and `y` value to scroll to, so if you keep passing in the same `y` value, you will keep scolling to the same place, not further down the page. Do my multiplying the `scrollHeight` by the loop counter, you ensure you keep scrolling further down the page.